# How config React to render .js

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, rubymine

I'm trying to let WebStorm to render the .js files for me watching .jsx files.

I'm using or trying to use browserify/babelify and react nodes but I'm getting the following error

```
/usr/local/bin/browserify -t [babelify --presets react]
/Users/myUser/Developer/ApacheRoot/JsFrameworksSamples/ReactJs/Sample_2/src/*
-o /Users/myUser/Developer/ApacheRoot/JsFrameworksSamples/ReactJs/Sample_2/src/bundle.js
Error: Cannot find module
'/Users/myUser/Developer/ApacheRoot/JsFrameworksSamples/ReactJs/Sample_2/src/*'
from
<br>'/Users/myUser/Developer/ApacheRoot/JsFrameworksSamples/ReactJs/Sample_2/src'
    at <br>/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load <br>(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex <br>(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at <br>/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at<br> FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)<br>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The configuration for the file watcher is the following:

[image]

arguments: `-t [babelify --presets react] $FileDir$/*  -o $FileDir$/bundle.js`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For reference: same question on JB forums: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/475946?tstart=0

Comment: this is me...I post the same question also on jetbrains forum

Comment: nobody uses webstorm with react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK....I got the solution...

browseify cannot use wildcard (as *) so it should transpile individual files using the following arguments:

> -t [babelify --presets react] $FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.jsx  -o $FileDir$/../dist/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js

after that when you want to bundle all .jsx files, it can run the following command:

> browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] src/* -o dist/bundle.js